# MEF - No exports were found that match the constraint

Tags: c#, mef

So I have this one class from which I'm trying to import some constructors:

```
[Export]
public partial class MainWindow
{
        private readonly MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;
        private readonly IEnumerable<IApplicationClosingListener> _applicationClosingListeners;
        private readonly Lazy<IPreferencesRepository> _preferencesRepository;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public MainWindow(MainWindowViewModel viewModel, IViewManager viewManager, [ImportMany] IEnumerable<IApplicationClosingListener> applicationClosingListeners, Lazy<IPreferencesRepository> preferencesRepository)
        {
            _doStuff();
        }
}
```

I'm also exporting all the classes that I'm trying to import (`MainWindowViewModel`, `IViewManager` and `IPreferencesRepository`). I do this this way:

`MainWindowViewModel` and `IViewManager` classes:

```
    [Export]
    [Export(typeof(IViewManager))]
    [Export(typeof(IMessagePresenter))]
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel, IViewManager, IApplicationClosingListener
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public MainWindowViewModel(
            Lazy<IPreferencesRepository> preferencesRepository)
        {
            _doStuff();
        }
```

And finally, `IPreferencesRepository` class:

```
[Export(typeof(IPreferencesRepository))]
    public class PreferencesRepository : IPreferencesRepository
    {
        private readonly IPreferencesStorage _preferencesStorage;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public PreferencesRepository(IPreferencesStorage preferencesStorage, IPreferencesSerializer preferencesSerializer)
        {
            _doStuff();
        }
```

Now the problem occurs when I'm trying to get and use the exported `MainWindow` class:

```
var container = new CompositionContainer(new ApplicationCatalog());
container.ComposeExportedValue((IApplication)this);
var mainWindow = container.GetExport<MainWindow>(); // here the exception is thrown.
```

The `ImportCardinalityMismatchException` is thrown. Also, in the debug console I get three messages that are telling me that "***No exports were found that match the constraint***".

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you don't have export of `IPreferencesSerializer`.
Also I think your `MainWindowViewModel` should export `IApplicationClosingListener`